# Stop animated counter script from running

Tags: javascript

I have recently implemented the counter shown in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/osqzL4ob/

HTML

```
<div id="users">Counter: <b counter="0">0</b></div>
```

JS

```
    function update_users_count() {
    $('#users b').animate({
        counter: 260
    }, {
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        },
        complete: update_users_count
    });
};

update_users_count();
```

In the element inspector it looks as if the script would continue to loop after execution (the value is highlighted and keeps refreshing). Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Seems the problem is caused by your extra `complete: update_users_count` in `animate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just remove the `complete: update_users_count` (what it does is: recursively looping the same function on *"complete"*, although the value stays the same in its final state count).

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m4erh587/)